# Cannnot fetch contact no. using where clause in php

Tags: php, mysql

```
echo $query = "SELECT user_id FROM login WHERE username = '8578896785'";
echo $result = $mysql_query($query);
cannot fetch contact number when use in php
```

I executed the same query on mysql and it gives results. The same query does not work in PHP.

The column is of varchar(200) datatype and contains data as string,alphanumeric as well as numbers

Comment: Please have a look at the manual page of [mysql_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). You will see examples how to get your values and you will see a nice red box, that those mysql_* functions are deprecated. Please follow the advice to use PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: Hint: don't echo result. Fetch data from it and echo that. Too trivial to justify an answer

Comment: is this typo? `$mysql_query`?, you need to fetch the results first by the way

Answer (score 0):

if u use numeric date to fetch then u have to use 
SELECT user_id FROM login WHERE username = 123 withought ''

and when you try to fetch string data 
SELECT user_id FROM login WHERE username = 'abc' with ''

Answer (score 0):

you can't output a resource with the echo statement, you have to fetch the data in the result before you can output it.

```
$query = "SELECT user_id FROM login WHERE username = '8578896785' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['user_id'];
```

1st Edit: removed unnecessary echo's
2nd Edit: adding a LIMIT 1 to your query, the username schould be just one time in the table ;)
3rd Edit: removed $ in front of a function (mysql_query())
4th Edit: fetching data from the ressource (as array, for other methods to fetch the data look into the php manuals)
5th Edit: output the userid